# Shapefiles misalign with Google Maps when exporting from Print Composer

Tags: qgis, google

I've built a project with several shapefiles and Google Satellite as a background. Everything seems to be perfectly fine, I manage to prepare the Print Layout but when I finally save as image or PDF, the Google Satellite imagery becomes misaligned with the shapefiles.

I've tried reprojecting all SHPs to EPSG 3857, with no change in the final result. How can I solve this?